# Find $c$ when $P(X = x) = c(1/3)^x$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this problem:
$$P(X=x)=\begin{cases}
 c\,(\frac{1}{3})^x& \text{for } x = 1,2,3,\dotsc\\
0& \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Find the constant $c$ and find the mode of this distribution. Now, if I had the PDF $f(x)$ or the CDF $F(X)$ I'd know how to find $c$, but I'm unsure how to find either starting from $P(X)$. Must be very obvious, but I don't see it.

Comment: Total probability is $1$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}P(X=x)=1\implies$

$\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}c\cdot\left(\frac13\right)^x=1\implies$

$c\cdot\sum\limits_{x=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac13\right)^x=1\implies$

$c\cdot\frac{1}{3-1}=1\implies$

$c\cdot\frac{1}{2}=1\implies$

$c=2$